# How to loop through textboxes of i amount?

Tags: c#, wpf, loops, textbox

I need to check text and various properties of unlimited amount of textboxes. I though i might be able to do it the way below using {i} (so it would check through tbEavelength1,tbEavelength2, tbEavelength3 etc. ) this doesn't work was wondering if anyone had any ideas?

```
for (int i = 1; i <= comboBox1.SelectedIndex + 1; i++)
{
    if (tbEaveLength{i}.IsEnabled == false)
    {
        eaveLength{i} = 0;
    }
    else if (tbEaveLength{i}.Text == "")
    {
        throw new Exception("EaveLength {i} must have a value");
    }
    else if (!double.TryParse(tbEaveLength{i}.Text, out eaveLength{i}))
    {
       throw new Exception("EaveLength {i} must be numerical");
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: There is no defined way of looping over an unlimited set. At least you never will be done.

Comment: @MareInfinitus That's probably a bad phrasing because of ESL. Obviously you couldn't display an infinite amount of textboxes on a screen.

Comment: !Unlimited!... that's a lot of RAM :o)

Answer (score 1):

What's about create a `List<TextBox>` and then get a textbox using indexes and do the same thing with lenght using a `List<double>`?

```
//List<TextBox> listTextBoxes = new List<TextBox>();
//populate the list of textboxes

//List<double> listEaveLength = new List<double>();

for (int i = 1; i <= comboBox1.SelectedIndex + 1; i++)
{
    if (listTextBoxes[i].IsEnabled == false)
    {
        listEaveLength[i] = 0;
    }
    else if (listTextBoxes[i].Text == "")
    {
        throw new Exception(listTextBoxes[i].Name +  " must have a value");
    }
    else if (!double.TryParse(listTextBoxes[i].Text, out listEaveLength[i]))
    {
        throw new Exception(listTextBoxes[i].Name + " must be numerical");
    }
}
```

---

As said *millimoose* manage a parallel arrays could be hard and not the better solution.
So you can create a class like this:

```
class DataStructure
{
   public TextBox Textbox
   {
      get;
      set;
   }

   public double Lenght
   {
      get;
      set;    
   }

   public DataStructure(TextBox Textbox)
   {
      this.Textbox = Textbox;
   }
}
```

Then always using a `List<DataStructure>`:

```
//List<DataStructure> myList = new LList<DataStructure>();
//myList.Add(new DataStructure(myTextBox));
//... populate your list

for (int i = 1; i <= comboBox1.SelectedIndex + 1; i++)
{
    if (myList[i].Textbox.IsEnabled == false)
    {
        myList[i].Lenght = 0;
    }
    else if (myList[i].Textbox.Text == "")
    {
        throw new Exception(myList[i].Textbox.Name +  " must have a value");
    }
    else if (!double.TryParse(myList[i].Textbox.Text, out myList[i].Lenght))
    {
        throw new Exception(myList[i].Textbox.Name + " must be numerical");
    }
}
```

Comment: It'd probably be better to create a data structure to hold the `TextBox` and the associated `int`. Parallel arrays are clunky.

Comment: Yeah, you're right It could be another solution.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can try to find the textbox by using FindControl() method. I assume you are working on Asp.net page.

Eg.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= comboBox1.SelectedIndex + 1; i++)
{
    var tbEaveLength = FindControl("tbEaveLength" + i);
    if (tbEaveLength.IsEnabled == false)
    {
        eaveLength = 0;
    }
    else if (tbEaveLength.Text == "")
    {
        throw new Exception("EaveLength {i} must have a value");
    }
    else if (!double.TryParse(tbEaveLength{i}.Text, out eaveLength{i}))
    {
        throw new Exception("EaveLength {i} must be numerical");
    }
 }
```

Comment: sorry wasn't clear this is in a wpf

Comment: OK. you might want to read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/636383/wpf-ways-to-find-controls
Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

If you are in your code behind file, then you can use method `FindName` to get the instance of a textbox by passing its name and then can perform operation on that particular textbox like this -

```
for (int i = 1; i <= comboBox1.SelectedIndex + 1; i++)
{
    TextBox textBox = (TextBox)FindName("tbEaveLength" + i);
    if (textBox.IsEnabled == false)
    {
        eaveLength{i} = 0;
    }
    else if (textBox.Text == "")
    {
        throw new Exception("EaveLength {i} must have a value");
    }
    else if (!double.TryParse(textBox.Text, out eaveLength{i}))
    {
       throw new Exception("EaveLength {i} must be numerical");
    }
}
```